# Swift: When i pass a parameter to a function does the function copies the parameter or uses the reference to that parameter

Tags: swift

When i pass a parameter to a swift function does the function copies the parameter or does it uses the reference to that parameter.
On value types (struct, enum, tuple) I am sure that the argument is copied to the function.
The question is on reference types (objects), what does it happens when they are passed as argument to a swift function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a reference type into a swift function you are passing along a reference to that object, so any changes that you make to the object in that method will effect that object outside the function. You can achieve a similar effect for value types if you label them as inout parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Reference types are passed by reference.

Comment: So what is the deference of an in-out reference with a var reverence?

Comment: If a reference object is passed as `inout`, the object itself can be replaced.  If it isn't passed as `inout`, only its properties can be changed.